# isEmpty() Always returning false

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA function called getYear that is initialized as follows :

`Public Function getYear(ByVal year As Date, Optional ByVal month As Date) As Long`

Then, inside the function I have :

`msg = MsgBox(IsEmpty(month), vbOKOnly)` So I know whether or not the month has been input in the function.

The only thing is whether I have a function call such as : `getYear(currentYear)` or `getYear(currentYear, currentMonth)` `isEmpty` is always returning `False`

If I am understanding this correctly when I call `getYear(currentYear)` `isEmpty()` should return `True`, but it is not...

I gather that is from my function initialization, but I don't know what else to do.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you could use `MsgBox IsMissing(month)`, but it works only with `Variant` type. So, use this one instead: `Public Function getYear(year, Optional month) As Long`. [Msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251721(v=office.15).aspx).

Comment: your function takes up to two dates, and returns the year -- what if the dates entered are in different years?  Are you sure you don't really want two integers, one representing the year and one representing the month (1-12)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN:

```
IsEmpty only returns meaningful information for variants
```

You can also use `IsMissing()` to check if an optional argument was passed to the function, but this works only on Variants as well. You might want to check if the optional argument has a value equal to his default value, which is zero for dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a default value for "month" that is zero or negative, or out of the range of possible entries.  Then instead of using IsMissing or IsEmpty, you can just test for that default value. If month = the default, you know that parameter was not passed to the function.